# Drupal & View Custom Field & PHP

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

Wondered if someone could assist me, I have no PHP knowledge so im struggling a bit.
I have installed the following modules
To Do List Module - http://drupal.org/project/to_do
View Custom Field - http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield - Field that allows usage of custom PHP code (with access to view's database result)

**I created a view with the following fields:**

```
User: Uid (excluded from display)
Node: Title  
To do list: Deadline  
To do list: Priority  
To do list: Start date  
To do list: Status  
To do assigned users: Assigned user ID (excluded from display)  
To do list: Buttons (excluded from display)  
Customfield: PHP code
```

**The following Tokens/Replacement Patterns are available based on the above fields**

```
* [uid] == User: Uid
* [title] == Node: Title
* [deadline] == To do list: Deadline
* [priority] == To do list: Priority
* [start_date] == To do list: Start date
* [item_status] == To do list: Status
* [uid_field] == To do assigned users: Assigned user ID
* [buttons] == To do list: Buttons
* [phpcode] == Customfield: PHP code
* [markup] == Customfield: Markup
```

**What I would like to accomplish is:**

As, the button field has been excluded, I am trying to use the Customfield, to display   that button. But only display that button if the current user is the author of the To Do node.

**What ive aded to Customfield PHP code**

```
<?php  
global $user;  
$data->to_do_assigned_users;  
if ($user->uid == $data->uid_field)  
{  
print '[buttons]';  
}  
?>
```

**What's happening**
Nothing displays using the above code.

I know the [buttons] token works because when I use the following code, it displays the button.

```
<?php  
print '[buttons]';  
?>
```

So I assume something needs to be added so that the system can decide whether the current logged in user is the author of the node. Both the [UID] & [UID_FIELD] always display the same value if I ouput it, so I thuogh that would work but it doesn't.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Charles

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Charles

Comment: Try `print_r($data)` to make sure the views data is named what you think it is. `$data`'s identifiers aren't always what you'd expect. Also, `$data->to_do;` doesn't do anything.

Comment: I get the following,  stdClass Object ( [nid] => 72 [users_uid] => 1 [node_title] => another test task [to_do_deadline] => [to_do_priority] => 1 [to_do_start_date] => [to_do_item_status] => 2 [to_do_assigned_users_uid] => 1 [to_do_nid] => 72 )

Comment: So ive changed my code to:  <?php
global $user;
if ($user->users_uid == $data->to_do_assigned_users_uid)
{
print '[buttons]';
}
?>

Comment: changed $user=uid and that worked. Thanks fo much for the help :)